# Parsing email timestamps in Delphi/FreePascal

Tags: delphi, datetime, freepascal

Using FreePascal (FPC) 2.6.2 I'd like to convert into DateTime values some timestamp strings from email messages *(retrieved from an IMAP server using Synapse `IMAPsend`)*:

```
Date: Thu, 1 Aug 2013 20:07:43 -0400
```

From what I've read of `StrToDateTime()` and `TFormatSettings`, I don't see a way to do this directly. They typically expect strings like `1/8/2013 20:07:47` with formats like `dd/mm/yyyy` & `hh:mm:ss` and have no way to handle the UTC offset.

Is it necessary for me to first chop-up and rearrange the string and do my own conversion of short month-names and offsets?

Comment: I don't know FreePascal but isn't there something if you search the help for'timestamp', 'timezone' or 'utc'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you use Synapse; in **synautil.pas** file you can find **DecodeRfcDateTime** function.  With this function you can do what you ask.